# Footnote - larger than textwidth

Tags: footnotes, width

I am having some issues with \footnote{...} . I have defined the margins of my document and the textwidth. However, everytime I include a footnote it streches until the margins of the document thus becoming much larger than the actual text width. I tried to change the margins to the actual textwidth but I was not able to do it.

Can anyone help me?

Below a dummy example:

```
    %2multibyte Version: 5.50.0.2890 CodePage: 65001

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage[autolinebreaks]{mcode0}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,margin=\parindent,tableposition=top]{caption}
\usepackage{rotating}
%\usepackage{showframe}
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{10}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={210mm,297mm},
 left=14mm,
 right=14mm,
 top=21mm,
 bottom=21mm,
 }

%\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-.875in}
%   \addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-.875in}
%   \addtolength{\textwidth}{1.75in}
%   \addtolength{\topmargin}{-.875in}
%   \addtolength{\textheight}{1.75in}

\parskip = 0pt
\pagestyle{plain}
\setlength{\parskip}{.0in}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3}


\newenvironment{Question}[2][Question]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2.}]}{\end{trivlist}}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{gobble}
\title{Title...}
\date{}
\author{Volcompt}
\maketitle

\abstract{ABSTRACT HERE }

\vspace{50 mm}
\begin{center}
    [VERY PRELIMINARY AND INCOMPLETE]
 \end{center}


\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\section{Introduction}


Some random text here. A stock option is a contract between two people that gives the holder the right, but not the obligation, to buy or sell outstanding stocks at a specific price and at a specific date. Options are purchased when it is believed that the price of a stock will go up or down (depending on the option type). For example, if a stock currently trades at 40 and you believe the price will rise to 50 next month, you would buy a call option today so that next month you can buy the stock for 40, sell it for 50, and make a profit of 10. Stock options trade on a securities exchange, just like stocks.

A stock warrant is just like a stock option because it gives you the right to purchase a company's stock at a specific price and at a specific date. However, a stock warrant differs from an option in two key ways:

A stock warrant is issued by the company itself New shares are issued by the company for the transaction. Unlike a stock option, a stock warrant is issued directly by the company. When a stock option is exercised, the shares usually are received or given by one investor to another; when a stock warrant is exercised, the shares that fulfill the obligation are not received from another investor, but directly from the company. \footnote{footnote off margins}
\end{document}
```

Thanks

Comment: Why not use `geometry` package to control the margins?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I change the preamble to include : \usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={210mm,297mm},
 left=14mm,
 right=14mm,
 top=21mm,
 bottom=21mm,
 }

And removed the previous setup. However the footnotes still go beyond margins ...

Comment: Use `\usepackage[showframe,a4paper,left=14mm,right=14mm,top=21mm,bottom=21mm]{geometry}`. Then you can see the position of contents. Please, add a minimal code showing the footnote.

Comment: without an example showing a wide footnote it is impossible to say why your footnotes are wide.

Comment: Thanks. I have edited the question and included a dummy example with the full preamble.

Comment: The problem is in `\abstract{ABSTRACT HERE }`. Use `\begin{abstract}foo\end{abstract}` instead. Also, use `showframe` option into `geometry` so you can see the body.

Comment: Note that `abstract` is an environment and not a command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Sigur.

> The problem is in `\abstract{ABSTRACT HERE}`. Use
>   `\begin{abstract}foo\end{abstract}` instead. Also, use `showframe` option
>   into `geometry` so you can see the body.